# can not download files from google drive ios. showing "daily limit exceeded"

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

i am using google drive api to fetch and download a file in my application. I successfully fetched the list of all file what i have on my drive.But when i want to download the file by GTMSessionFetcher ,it shows me this error in my console **"Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "**(null)""
                     And when i tried to hit the url on the browser ,it shows me this

```
**{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 } 
}**
```

i don't understand  why this  is happening . On your error handling page they are saying that i need to request some additional quota thats why i requested for quota. Please help me sir to get rid of this problem as soon as possible ,i've wasted much time for a solution.

thats how i am trying to download

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf",[self.listPAtharray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@"url is %@",url);
    GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url];

    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
            // Do something with data
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

here list path array stores all the file ids

Comment: Are you authenticating?

Comment: This error could mean you have exceeded the daily limit, or it could mean a configuration error.  Can you share any code with us?

Comment: sorry i forgot something ,thats how i am trying to download the file .

Comment: what kinda code you want?

Comment: i followed google drive api integration tutorial step by step...is there any additional work i'd have to  do for authenticating? @Avi

Answer (score 1):

Suggested action for your encountered error is to request additional quota but if you already have done so and still issue persists, please try authenticating users as also suggested in [Drive Platform Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/practices).

You may implement the following to help you build high quality Google Drive apps.

1. **Authenticating users**

   - Use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and [Google's identity APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/) to authenticate new and existing users. Whenever you can avoid it, don't require users to create new passwords for your application.
2. Authorizing access

   - The OAuth 2.0 framework for Drive apps solves a lot of authorization challenges.
3. Handling errors: revoked or invalid tokens

   - Google Drive apps should account for the API returning an HTTP 401 or HTTP 403 response when calling the Drive API.
4. Gracefully handling declined access requests
5. Opening and creating files
6. Handling shared files
7. Improving performance
8. Handling API errors

   - Drive apps should catch and handle all errors that might be encountered when using the REST API. See [Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) for a reference of the errors returned by the API.

You may go through the given documentations for more information.

Comment: How to regenerate token ?